# Laravel: Pagination only returning first chunk

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, laravel-5.4

I pull in the paginated data via AJAX requests in my Laravel application. This works fine for the first chunk. For the following however, it's only passing one column (the id).

What is the problem?

The relevant code:

```
Route::get('contacts', function (Request $request) {
    return buildQuery($request, User::class)->simplePaginate(50);
});

function buildQuery(Request $request, $model) {
    $query = DB::table('users')->select('id as ID');
    $properties = $request->all();

    $searchString = "";
    if (in_array('q', array_keys($properties)) && $properties['q']) {
        $searchString = $properties['q'];
        $query->orWhere('id', 'like', '%'.$searchString.'%');
    }

    foreach ($properties as $property => $value) {
        if ($property == "id" || $property == "q")
            continue;

        if (in_array($property, array_keys($model::$labels))) {
            $query->addSelect($property.' as '.$model::$labels[$property]);

            if ($value == "desc" || $value == "asc")
                $query->orderBy($property, $value);

            if ($searchString)
                $query->orWhere($property, 'like', '%'.$searchString.'%');
        }
    }

    return $query;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because the query params are not appended to the subsequent pagination requests.

Update your logic inside the Route to:

```
Route::get('contacts', function (Request $request) {
    return buildQuery($request, User::class)->paginate(50)->appends($request->all());
});
```

OR

```
Route::get('contacts', function (Request $request) {
        return buildQuery($request, User::class)->simplePaginate(50)->appends($request->all());
    });
```

Comment: Leads to: BadMethodCallException: Method append does not exist.

Comment: ok, my bad. It works with LengthAwarePaginator. If you need it for Simple Pagination, use the appends on the results returned by your query while building the links from it.

Comment: same error. the object append is called on is an AbstractPaginator

Comment: ok, I mistyped. It should be "appends" with a 's'. And it should work for both paginate and simplePaginate methods.

Comment: You have well-deserved the tick^^